# https and subdomains - not working

Tags: apache, ssl, https, cpanel, subdomain

I want to start hosting some of my old domains/websites as sub domains of my main website.

For my live website I've used the Subdomain Creation tool in cpanel to set one up. This works as expected when browsing normally.
For localhost I had to do some tweaking in the settings but did get this working there as well.
However, if I try changing to https the sub domain fails to be accessed on live and instead the request is done on the main domain.

E.g.

```
http://domain.co.uk/about
https://domain.co.uk/about
```

both correctly return the 'about' page in my main domain folder; and

```
http://subdomain.domain.co.uk/about
```

correctly returns the 'about' page in my subdomain folder; but

```
https://subdomain.domain.co.uk/about
```

incorrectly returns the 'about' page in my main domain folder.

When I try the https for the subdomain under localhost I get a 404 (Object not found!) error and the following is logged in the error log file: *AH02199: SSL not enabled on vhost*

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this just not possible (without a lot of work)?

Note: I'm not too worried about fixing this on localhost as I can disable https when developing - I've just posted the info here for reference.

Comment: A. Did you enable https for that subdomain? You have to tell apache to use https for a site. B. Do you have a valid cert for that subdomain? You will need to do both of those.

Comment: It's a hosted domain so I only have access to cpanel - so not sure about enabling https for subdomains.
I registered domain.co.uk for the certificate and so was under the impression this would work on all subdomains.

Comment: No, that cert is only valid for domain.co.uk. If that was the case there wouldn't be a need for wildcard certs. You will have to buy a ceft for each sub domain you want, or buy a wildcard cert to cover any amount of subdomains you want. You need to get `*.domain.uk.co`. They are always more expensive as well. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate

Comment: Oh ok. As it works ok for `www.domain.co.uk` I assumed it would for any subdomain. I guess `www.` is the only exception then? Strange that the default behaviour under this circumstance is to ignore the subdomain, not load the subdomain page and give a certificate error.

Comment: Most registrars will give `www` for free because that is the most common part of a domain name and that's what people naturally type in. So yes that's the only exception. The other reason it might not give a ceft error is your cpanel setup. It probably doesn't recognize https as I mentioned before. I don't use conrrol panels on my servers as they are often bottlenecks on production servers. Ask your host or check WHM's site for info.

Comment: Thanks for the info @panama-jack. It's been useful. Knowing now that there will be extra cost involved with using subdomains, and given the trouble I have getting this working on localhost, I think I may approach this differently.